# Jquery/Ajax or PHP sessions to enter data in DB with Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I would like to get an idea of what a "Best Practice" may be. I am redeveloping a web app I made, that allows users to select items from a dropdown list, add them to a "Queue" and then allows the user to save them to the DB as their user when the info is finished being entered.

Currently, I am using, Jquery/Ajax to get the data from the selections, add it an array, then append it to the Queue Table.

When the user clicks save, it passes the array through ajax to PHP to send it to the database.

I am recreating this application in laravel, and wonder if it would be better to store the user defined data into a session and then pass it directly to the php script to insert it into a database.

I am not familiar as familiar as I would like to be with sessions, so I would like your advice if this is worth pursuing or if I would be using sessions wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP script that will receive the Ajax data is an API.  The user needs to be previously *authenticated* via a session or token, but when the Ajax call is made, you need to parse the data received and immediately pass it to your database storage routines.